# Empty jQuery selectors breaking the rest of the script

Tags: jquery, ajax

Each page of my site has a different set of jQuery effects as well as forms that are submitted using ajax. I'm running into an issue where an empty jQuery selector prevents the rest of the javascript from running. Example:

```
// site.js
$(document).ready(function() {

function changeText() {
$("#div1").html("Test 1");
$("#div2").html("Test 2");
}

$("#button1").click(changeText());
$("#button2").click(changeText());

});

// page1.html
<script src="/static/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/static/site.js"></script>
<div id="div1">Div 1</div>
<input type="button" value="Change" id="button1"> <!-- Works //-->

// page2.html
<script src="/static/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/static/site.js"></script>
<div id="div2">Div 2</div>
<input type="button" value="Change" id="button2"> <!-- Doesn't work //-->
```

My solution so far has been to create separate javascript files for every page, but there must be another way. Any ideas? Do I really need to wrap every selector in an `if $("selector").length` call so the script doesn't break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you dont need to check for `empty` or `undefined` in `jquery`, it is `implicitly` done by `jquery`.

also you can rewrite the code as below, less code better performance

```
$("#button1,#button1").click(function(){
   $("#div1").html("Test 1");
   $("#div2").html("Test 2");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reaffirming that jQuery does this automatically. Turns out the problem was a call to `document.getElementById()` that was breaking everything. I switched that to a jQuery call and everything is fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is the problem but you are not declaring your click event handlers correctly:

```
$("#button1").click(changeText());
```

If you put parenthesis, the function is called directly.

Should be:

```
$("#button1").click(changeText);
```

As far as I know, jQuery always returns, if no DOM element was matched it simply contains no element (length = 0).

Comment: What if I need to pass an argument so I can do a typical `e.preventDefault();`?

Also, when declaring functions like I do in my example, should those go inside a `$(document).ready()` function or not?

Comment: When calling the event handler, jquery will automatically pass the event object, just declare the parameter in your function `function changeText(e) {...}`. You don't have to put them in the ready handler.